# Magento2 FilterableAttributeListInterface error

Tags: magento2

Which interface instantiation is missing  in my constructor

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver as LayerResolver;
use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection;
use Magento\CatalogSearch\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation;
use Magento\Search\Model\QueryFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterableAttributeListInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\AvailabilityFlagInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList;

class Result extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

   protected $tglssearchHelper;
   protected $catalogLayer;
   public function __construct(
   Context $context,
    LayerResolver $layerResolver,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList $filterList,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\AvailabilityFlagInterface $visibilityFlag,
    \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $tglssearchHelper,
    QueryFactory $queryFactory,
    FilterableAttributeListInterface $filterableAttributes,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
    $this->tglssearchHelper = $tglssearchHelper;
    $this->queryFactory = $queryFactory;
    $this->filterableAttributes = $filterableAttributes;
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $data
    );
}

 protected function _prepareLayout()
  {

    $this->renderer = $this->getChildBlock('renderer');
    foreach ($this->filterList->getFilters($this->_catalogLayer) as $filter) {
        $filter->apply($this->getRequest());
    }
    $this->getLayer()->apply();
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
 }
}
```

my etc di

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Result\Index" />
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Category\View" />
<preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Result" />
<preference for="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Navigation" />
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ListProduct" />
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />
 <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection" type="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection" />
<!-- <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection">
    <plugin name="mymoduletag" type="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection" sortOrder="10"/>
</type> -->
 </config>
```

I get :

> Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterableAttributeListInterface in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2x_2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php on line 73

Comment: is this your own class or a core one? And if it's your own, are you trying to use it on frontend or backend?

Comment: Please see updated answer .. to use filterList i have used as above

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use this `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\AvailabilityFlagInterface` as a dependency for a class that you are going to use in the backend, you need to add this to the `adminhtml/di.xml` of your module

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\AvailabilityFlagInterface" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\AvailabilityFlag" />
```

If you are going to use it on frontend it should work without any issues.

This happens because the preference (the class to use by default by the object manager) for the interface `Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\AvailabilityFlagInterface` is declared in `app/code/Magento/LayeredNavigation/etc/frontend/di.xml` so it only works for frontend.

Comment: Please see updated answer .. to use filterList i have used as above

Comment: updated my etc di in answer as well

Comment: i added AvailabilityFlagInterface in an assumption that error was thrown because of some missing dependencies, nyways im not using this AvailabilityFlagInterface, i need filterList(i suppose its from LayeredNavigation) which i need it in my Result.php

Comment: any update on this? @Marius

Comment: @SachinS I have no other idea.